# How ro register/activate keyboard up handler for a text field in AppleScript

Tags: events, keyboard, applescript

I'd like to have an AppleScript that would react to key press events.
I found this post http://foolsworkshop.com/applescript/index.html%3Fp=21.html. 
Now I can imagine an acceptable solution for me: the script opens a dialog describing possible options:

```
a - show notification
b - play sount
etc...
```

The only bit that I'm missing is how to register/activate such keyboard up event handler for my dialog?

In the post, there is a link with description how to do it with some GUI builder, but there must be a way to just code it in plain AppleScript, right?

Like:

```
display dialog "Enter your text here..." with keyboard down event handler
```

Comment: The linked article is from 2008 and related to AppleScript Studio which Apple discontinued in 2009. Basically you cannot do that in plain AppleScript

Comment: You can use Hammerspoon ( Free and Open source) or Fast Scripts (Free & Padi)  or keyboard maestero ( Paid) tools to do the hotkey triggering